# Predictions on Xgboost DMatrix Object with XgBoostClassifier

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am working with a pretrained model on AWS SageMaker,

I need to provide a `predict_fn` which will do actual prediction.

```
def predict_fn(request_body, model):
    prediction = model.predict(request_body)
    return prediction
```

This returns an error: `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype(‘O’),)`

model is an object of `XGboostClassifier`, `requestbody` is an object of `xgboost.core.DMatrix`

Answer (score 0):

Have you also implemented your own model_fn and input_fn methods? I would advise that you try debugging this locally first, since it does not seem to be sagemaker specific.